# Is it possible to set a breakpoint in Visual Studio via command line?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, command-line, breakpoints

Sometimes, I grep over all my sources to find a certain symbol (for example an error code) and want to set a breakpoint in Visual Studio on every occurrence of this symbol.

Currently, I walk through the files manually and hit <kbd>F9</kbd> on every line where I want to break.

Could I do that with the **command line** too?